# Reading a resource with BufferedReader

Tags: java, jar, resources, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a resource that will be included into a .JAR, but I get a nullPointer
for the following:

```
bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/" + fileName)));
```

Using a File however, works fine..

```
bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/" + fileName)));
```

Comment: Can you print out the stack trace of the error please.

Comment: What's the fully quelified name of `this.getClass()`, and where is the file in the jar?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)

Answer (score 30):

Assuming your IDE/Maven/ANT/Gradle/build process will include contents of "resources" in jar at root, try finding it at "/".

```
bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                           this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName)));
```

**UPDATE:**

Make sure the "resources" folder is configured as a resource folder.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and I get the NullPointer when running it in Eclipse. The .jar has nothing to do with the problem, other than the fact that I would have used the example for a File, if no plans for creating a .jar in the end.

Comment: I can find the file using "/" if the files are drag-dropped into the project folder, but then it can't be found from an executable jar.

Comment: It is advisable to specify the encoding explicitly when creating the InputStreamReader

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Spring framework project? Try:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("XML_Request.xml").getInputStream()));
```

Resource to load is sitting in the src/main/resources directory:

[image: Resource to load is sitting in the src/main/resources directory]

Answer (score 1):

Set "resources" folder as a resource folder.
Try this code:

```
bReader = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename)`, the version you are using `getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)` uses a path relative to the class's location, rather than the classpath root. You need to either use an absolute path `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + filename)` or use the `ClassLoader` version.

Also, make sure "resources" is on your classpath (if you are using Maven, it should be "src/main/resources" relative to your pom.xml). If so, you don't need to actually include "resources" in your filename, because that is the classpath root.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the reader class and the file to be read are in different packages. When `this.getClass().getRasourceAsStream("resource/file_name")` is called, it will search for the resource directory in the package directory where the current reader class presents if found then it will search for "file_name" file. So, if your file is not present it returns null.

In this case, you need to come back from current file reader class directory accordingly and then you have to give the path to your file. To back from a directory we should use `../`

For example, if
Reader class package : `package com.abc.util;`
File present in : `com.abc.template;`
Then you should call the `getResourceAsStream()` method as follows.

```
bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../template/" + fileName)));
```

Answer (score -1):

`this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/" + fileName)` loads file from classpath as `new File("resources/" + fileName)` loads file from your work dir(the project root dir in eclipse). To make the former work, you need to add the jar which containing `resources` dir to your classpath.